# Oracle Database 12c installation GUI issue

Tags: linux, oracle, installation

Is there any solution for oracle database 12c I installed on LINUX 7.4 but the Iinstallation GUI show me binary number how can i fix it
[image]

Comment: Looks like a missing font maybe, or incorrect default language?

Comment: I hop that is not the issue i can install weblogic other oracle product.

Comment: The problem solved by using this command  yum install evince.x86_64